# Calling clean up code in mod_perl environment

Tags: perl, mod-perl

Some quote to pick from practical mod_perl

*"Usually, a single process serves many requests before it exits, so END blocks cannot be used if they are expected to do something at the end of each request's processing."*

So, in my a.cgi script :

```
my $flag = 1;

END {
    # Value for $flag is undefined, if this script is run under mod_perl. 
    # END block code only executed when process to handle a.cgi exit. 
    # I wish to execute some code, just before process to handle a.cgi exit.
    if ($flag) {
        # clean up code.
    }
}
```

The book recommences $r->register_cleanup(sub { #cleanup } );

However,

1. How I can obtain $r in a.cgi script?
2. Can the subroutine access the my scope flag variable?
3. Is this $r->register_cleanup shall be placed at a.cgi script? I only want the cleanup code to be executed for a.cgi script. Not the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. my $r = Apache->request;
2. Yes, but see http://modperlbook.org/html/6-2-Exposing-Apache-Registry-Secrets.html and the next couple of pages, regarding scoping of local variables and functions.
3. Yes, only register the function if you want it to run.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you have a script you want to run both under mod_perl and as a plain CGI and it sounds like you are using [Apache::Registry](http://search.cpan.org/~gozer/mod_perl-1.31/lib/Apache/Registry.pm) to do this.

You have cleanup code that you want run *only* when you are running as CGI script.

You need to detect whether or  not you are running under mod_perl. That's fairly easy. The simplest way is to check your environment:

```
unless ($ENV{MOD_PERL})
{
   #... cleanup code here.
}
```

You only to register a cleanup handler if you want something to run when your script terminates under Apache::Registry.

If you do want that, you should place your cleanup code into a sub and call that sub from your check in the CGI:

```
unless ($ENV{MOD_PERL})
{
   cleanup_sub();
}
```

and from your cleanup handler:

```
my $r = Apache->request;
$r->register_cleanup(sub { cleanup_sub() } );
```